# SQL Question - Trying to derive the dates based on another column

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two columns in a table as shown below, report dates and forward dates. Each month we get a report date from external agencies for the next 12 months which is what the forward dates show. So in January 2023, we received a forecast for the next 12 months.

So in the subsequent months, the agencies drop the prior forecast months and start with the current month (logical - yes) but I would like to still bring their forecast points in from prior months. So in March I would ideally like to bring external agencies forecast from January (first two data points) and then add them to March's forecast. This way I am not ignoring their prior data points for a comparison and ensures a larger sample size.

Output I would like to have.

[image: 2023-01-01]

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do..

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, I have made some edits. Please tell me if this is helps?